# Listview inside edittext typting coverd by keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

List view content have edit text and text view. List view contents loaded dynamically while typing bottom of the listview edit text, the edit text filled not shown. Virtual keyboard covers the edit text.

I also have used this code in activity:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

I used adjustpan, resize, statevisible in manifest file, but nothing has changed.But it will working perfectly on below 4.0.

customlist.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"   android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="341dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
        android:background="@drawable/txt1"
        android:hint="Enter Value"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"  
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"  android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"  android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/app_text_color"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"   android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Large ryw4rtb "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/app_text_color"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and main.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:id="@+id/sceen"
    android:background="@drawable/full_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
        layout="@layout/title" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="326dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/left_bg" >

            <ListView 
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/left_table_bg"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:divider="@drawable/left_table_line"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_healthy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/right_side_bg" >
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_healthy1"   android:layout_above="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/available_right_bg"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:padding="20dp" />

             <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/available_right_bg"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

             <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/available_right_bg"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
           </RelativeLayout> 



        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/btn1" 
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="57dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bt_submit" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="57dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bt_reset" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
            </RelativeLayout>
              </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317157/android-adjustpan-not-working-after-the-first-time/15896264#15896264

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your manifest where your activity is declared.

```
     <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Comment: thanks,but nothing changed in layout,edit text is not visible when i typing in edit text at the bottom.

Comment: replace 'stateHidden' by 'adjustResize'

Comment: i tried using android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan" but nothing has changed.

Comment: LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS ,allow window to extend outside of the screen.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan" it will work on 2.2 not an 3.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `EditText` you are filling in, you definitely would have other view like a `Header` or `Button` etc..,

so,

**Track if the soft-keyboard is open and make these views visibility gone and make them visible when soft-keyboard is dismissed/hidden**

there is no direct way to track the soft-keyboard shown/hidden, hence use this code which i am using in my application:

```
//your_button is the layout of your button view or a header view. if its just a view cast it to

//appropriate Class
final LinearLayout your_button = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
//activityRootView is the Layout you are using for the Activity
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.layout_parent);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
    if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...

    your_button.setVisibility(Visibility.GONE);
    }else{

    your_button.setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i need to show edit text,when i am typing.But it goes to invisible.