# windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" work only one time

Tags: android, webview

I put the following line in AndroidMainfest

```
windowSoftInputMode = "adjustPan"
```

, but I had a problem, the page has 2 input fields username and password when zhatii on the first field (no matter your username or password) keyboard appears but there is no increase page, but if you click on the second box, then turns on the zoom and page increases that can be done that would page do not zoom?

Comment: what are u trying to say...what you want to do..

Comment: What do you even...?

Comment: I mean that i input login, zoom is off, but after press password activated zoom and it's not good. How can i zoom off?

Comment: This SO answer might help you [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15896264/2151075]

Comment: refer link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317157/android-adjustpan-not-working-after-the-first-time

Answer (score 0):

Its not *zoomed*. It must have been *panned* to make room for keyboard in a way that the edittext which is focused does not get hidden by keyboard.

**adjustPan**

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room
>   for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are
>   automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by
>   the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is
>   generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to
>   close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of
>   the window.

Read the description of all possible values over [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)