# Keyboard over EditText on second click

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, overlay

This is the picture:

[image]

When I click on the "Confirm password" EditText, for the first time, it works the way it should - layout pops up so I can enter text in selected EditText, but when I dismiss keyboard(that EditText still focused) and click on that same EditText again, it stays under keyboard.

Main layout is RelativeLayout, input fields are in ScrollView and buttons are in LinearLayout aligned to parent bottom.

In manifest I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`.

Is this some Android issue or I've been doing something wrong?

Comment: Try windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

Comment: Nope :/ Not the solution.

Comment: there are few other flags, try them.

Comment: I am also having same issue. did you get the solution

Answer (score 4):

It's actually a bug in `EditText`. try removing gravity of `EditText`, which could be either `center_horizontal` or `center`

Got the answer from another question. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26017060/1769274).

Answer (score 0):

For me removing `android:minWidth` does the trick

Answer (score -1):

I just came with a workaround for this problem as well, I got my edit text to start the text in the middle of the screen with a not so great solution, but it works for me. The code is this one:

```
        <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="130sp"
        android:paddingEnd="50sp"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"/>
```