# How to fix the keyboard hides my custom Edit Text issue without removing the gravity set for my edit text?

Tags: android-edittext, android-custom-view, keylistener, adjustpan, android-gravity

I am also running into the same problem as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317157/android-adjustpan-not-working-after-the-first-time) post.

As they mentioned in the comment, this issue was reported to google.

I searched over the net and I am not any finding any answer for the same.

Help me to fix the keyboard hides the Edit Text issue with using the gravity for my custom edit text.

Comment: Why aren't the solutions from the other question not working for you?

Comment: Yes we tried the other solution but nothing helps. We need to use adjustpan only, not adjustresize, because our layout design is like that.