# Push up the content each time click on editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a EditText field to enter a mobile number. It is at the bottom of the layout. I need to push the content up when I click in editText field so that it will not be covered by the soft keyboard.

I tried:

1. getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

in OnCreate, ClickListner, TouchListner

2. android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest.

Both the above methods helped me to push the content when i click the edittext field for the first time. but when i click the same field 2nd time the keyboard covers the field. i need to push the content each time I press the field.

What should i do for that?

Comment: share your code please

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317157/android-adjustpan-not-working-after-the-first-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android adjustpan not working after the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317157/android-adjustpan-not-working-after-the-first-time)